# How to create a program interface (style) like the one used in Visual Studio, Office 2013, GitHub for Windows, etc?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'd like to know how to create a program interface like the one used in Visual Studio, Office 2013, GitHub for Windows, etc.

**Looks like Cosmopolitan Theme for WPF is not the same theme used on those softwares.**

To show you the difference between these programs interfaces and common others take a look at those printscreens:

### Interfaces I wanna know how to build:

#### Visual Studio:

[image]

#### Office 2013 (Excel):

[image]

#### GitHub for Windows:

[image]

### Common Interface:

[image]

The difference between these programs is its interfaces. I already downloaded the Visual Studio Express for Windows 8, Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop and I also looked at Visual Studio Ultimate, but them doesn't have the option the build such kind of interfaces when you create a "New Project...".

Do I need to install a new Template on my VS to be able to build such kind of interface? I think it's some sort of theme for WPF. I'd like to see proves that those applications use this UI style you refer in your answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please note that the look and feel of the application is based on the operating system theme by default.

Your *Interfaces* have been designed following the [Metro UI style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29). Metro UI apps are Windows 8 only, as they require WinRT.

You can only *simulate* the Metro style in Windows 7 (and vista) with WPF : you have to use a third party controls (or develop your own), such as these examples :

- [Modern UI for WPF](http://mui.codeplex.com/)
- [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/)

Cosmopolitan is just a theme for common controls. For example, there are no pivot or panorama control.

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio 2012 and GitHub for Windows are WPF applications. Office uses custom controls for the "Metro" look.

WPF and Silverlight provide an easy way to theme an entire application. GitHub is based on the Silverlight theme "Cosmopolitan".

Here are some links for more information.

[Cosmopolitan Theme for WPF](http://cosmopolitanwpf.codeplex.com/)

[Making your WPF app look like the Zune client](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-your-wpf-app-look-like-zune.html)

[Silverlight 4 Application Themes](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14590)

[Mishra Reader](http://mishrareader.codeplex.com/) (An active open source WPF client with a similar theme)

Comment: @Zignd your 1st question was how do you build a program interface like the screenshots you provided - the links I gave you should get you going in the right direction. However, it doesn't answer your 2nd question about needing to install a new template. In that case no, a template is not available for VS to build these kind of interfaces.

Comment: Have a look at this http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7a4362a7-fe5d-4f9d-bc7b-0c0dc272fe31. It might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Office 2013 uses Metro Style and Ribbons. For this you can use [Fluent Control Suite](https://fluent.codeplex.com/). This project also has a Metro Style where you can easily make it like Office 2013. Note that you maybe need the recent dll instead of e.g. the nuget package.

If you want some icons like Office 2013, here i found an icon pack that is close to the Office icons: [Axialis Pure Flat 2013](http://www.axialis.com/stock-icons/pure-flat-2013-toolbar.html) (with costs).

For others without Ribbons, you can use for example [MahApps Metro](http://mahapps.com/) as Cybermaxs suggested and for the docks you can use [AvalonDock](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/) from the WPF Toolkit. AvalonDock also has a Metro Style. And a Visual Studio 2010 Style. And you can dock your Windows like in Visual Studio, very useful ;)